# hash function h(k) = k mod m

Tags: data-structures, hash, hash-function

For general integer keys and a table of size M, a prime number:

• a good fast general purpose hash function is H(K) = K mod M

can someone please explain what  H(K) = K mod M means or how it works im really confused what this hash function is supposed to represent

Answer (score 3):

K mod M is the remainder of K when divided by M. In many languages this is computed by the % operator. As K mod M will always be between 0 and M-1, we can always map an integer to one of the M slots.